# Does a colon followed by a type at the end of a signature have a different meaning based on context?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Does a colon followed by a type at the end of a signature have a different meaning depending on if it's appended to a function versus a method?

This is related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616480/what-does-a-colon-after-a-tuple-but-before-another-type-mean-within-a-method-sig) I posted in the past. However, that question was based on the context of a *method*.

For example, take the following functions:

```
type StateResponse<'state, 'event> = ('state * 'event) -> 'state

// Account * Event -> Account
let update1 : StateResponse<Account,Event> = function
    | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
    | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
    | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

// Account ** Doesn't compile**
let update2 : Account = function
    | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
    | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
    | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

// Account * Event -> Account
let update3 = function
    | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
    | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
    | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

// state:Account * event:Event -> Account
let update4 (state , event) =
    match   state , event with
    | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
    | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
    | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

// state:StateResponse<Account,Event> * event:Event -> StateResponse<Account,Event> ** Doesn't compile**
let update5 (state , event) : StateResponse<Account,Event> =
    match   state , event with
    | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
    | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
    | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }
```

**Function Context - Denotes an alias to a function?**

I assume that when a colon followed by a *function type* is appended to the end of a function name, then that **function name becomes the alias** to the *function type* that comes after the colon. This is the same convention that is used to provide aliases for parameters of a function or tuple elements.

*NOTE:*

I assume that a type that does NOT reflect a function cannot not be appended after the colon of a function signature (i.e. *update2*).

I also have reason to believe that a function name that aliases a function signature can not have explicit parameters declared before the colon (i.e. *update5*).

**Method Context - Denotes a return type?**

I assume that when a colon followed by a *type* is appended to the end of a method name followed by parameters, then that type that's appended at the end can be an arbitrary type (regardless if it's a function signature). This is contrary to the function context if applied.

**Are my assumptions accurate?**

**Appendix:**

```
namespace Domain

module EventSourcing =

    type StateResponse<'state, 'event> = ('state * 'event) -> 'state

module Account =

    open EventSourcing

    type AccountId = AccountId of string
    type FirstName = FirstName of string
    type LastName =  LastName  of string

    type Credentials =   { UserId:string; Password:string }
    type Account = {
         AccountId: AccountId
         FirstName: FirstName
         LastName:  LastName
         Balance:   decimal }

    and Event = 
        | LoggedIn  of Credentials
        | Deposited of balance: decimal
        | Withdrew  of balance: decimal

    (*Functions*)
    let getAccount credentials = {
        AccountId= AccountId "myAccountId"
        FirstName= FirstName "Scott"
        LastName= LastName   "Nimrod"
        Balance= 20000m }

    let update1 : StateResponse<Account,Event> = function
        | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
        | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
        | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

    let update2 : Account = function
        | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
        | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
        | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

    let update3 = function
        | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
        | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
        | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

    let update4 (state , event) =
        match   state , event with
        | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
        | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
        | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }

    let update5 (state , event) : StateResponse<Account,Event> =
        match   state , event with
        | account , LoggedIn  credentials ->   account
        | account , Deposited balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance + balance }
        | account , Withdrew  balance     -> { account with Balance=account.Balance - balance }
```

Answer (score 6):

A colon denotes the type of what's left of it. So when you write `let x : T = ...`, you're saying that the type of `x` is `T`. Here `T` should match the type of whatever comes after the `=`. So if that's a function, `T` should be a compatible function type, if it's something else, `T` should be that something else.

For example `let x : int = 42` and `let x : int -> int = function y -> y+1` are both valid while `let x : int -> int = 42` or `let x : int = function y -> y+1` would not be because `42` does not have the type `int -> int` and `function y -> y+1` does not have the type `int`.

Now when you use the shortcut syntax for defining functions, like `let f (x: ParameterType) : T`, then what's left of the last colon is `f(x : ParameterType)`, not `f`. So you're now saying what the type of `f(x)` is (or in other words what the return type of `f` is), not what the type of `f` is. And again this type should match the type of whatever comes after the `=`.

PS: Both `let f = function x -> ...` (or for that matter `let f = fun x -> ...`) and `let f x = ...` are exactly equivalent and define functions. Methods are defined using the `member` keyword and don't seem to be related to your question.