# What does it mean to upcast a value to the _ wildcard?

Tags: f#

What does it mean to implement a wildcard at the end of a case statement?

**Take the following syntax:**

```
match imp req with
| Success () -> this.Ok () :> _
```

**Is this the same as:**

```
| Success () -> this.Ok () :> IHttpActionResult
```

What is the advantage of writing that type of syntax?

**Here's the context of my question:**

```
type PushController (imp) =
    inherit ApiController ()

    member this.Post (portalId : string, req : PushRequestDtr) : IHttpActionResult =
        match imp req with
        | Success () -> this.Ok () :> _
        | Failure (ValidationFailure msg) -> this.BadRequest msg :> _
        | Failure (IntegrationFailure msg) ->
            this.InternalServerError (InvalidOperationException msg) :> _
```

Comment: It's not a wildcard, you're just letting the compiler infer the typecast for you based on the `Post` signature you provided.

Comment: Oh... So is the return type on the signature required for this to be inferred?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532637/type-mismatch-error-f-type-inference-fail

Comment: Yes. I'm not positive about this, but `| Success () -> this.Ok () :> IHttpActionResult` might allow you to use `_` in the rest of the cases without the return type in the signature. Try it out.

Comment: Shouldn't `upcast (this.Ok ())` sufficient here (and same principle for the other case) as the return type is specified, and also maybe more clearer ?

Comment: I'm going to edit the title to say "What does it mean to upcast a value to the _ wildcard?" instead, since that's a more accurate summary of the actual question being asked, and will be more likely to help anyone who finds this question in a search later on. Original title was "What does it mean to implement a wildcard at the end of a case statement?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator `:>` performs an *static upcast* to the type specified by the expression to its right side. The syntax for this operator is:

**:>** *expression*

That would be, for your example:

```
some_value :> IHttpActionResult
```

this tells the compiler that `some_value` is in fact an object that implements `IHttpActionResult`.

But according to the F# documentation:

> When you use the upcast operator, the compiler attempts to infer the
>   type you are converting to from the context. If the compiler is unable
>   to determine the target type, the compiler reports an error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/casting-and-conversions-%5Bfsharp%5D

Because the only type that can be returned by the `Post` method is `IHttpActionResult`, you can let the compiler infer it.

So, in this context this:

```
:> _
```

Is equivalent to:

```
:> IHttpActionResult
```